# ASUS RT AC68U no internet after switching from DD-WRT to stock/Merlin firmware

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

As written in the title.

After using the recovery tool to install the latest stock firmware from ASUS, the router has been unable to detect the modem to connect to the internet.

Changing it back to DD-WRT works.

What must I do to make this thing work with the stock firmware again?

Comment: What? I already wrote it in the title and post. The router is unable to detect the modem to connect to the internet after switching from DD-WRT to stock/Merlin.

Comment: Don't talk nonsense. Read the post, I quote myself. "After using the recovery tool to install the latest stock firmware from ASUS, the router has been unable to detect the modem to connect to the internet." How to be more specific? The router is unable to detect the modem to connect to the internet. Normally, it would detect the modem, but now it doesn't. Rebooting doesn't help. Factory reset doesn't help.

Comment: So the modem is a separate physical device? And they're connected by Ethernet? And the Ethernet link doesn't light up on either end? Or what?

Comment: Yes. Separate device. Connected by Ethernet. Modem detects the router, router does not detect the modem.

Comment: And the link lights don't come on for the Ethernet link?

Comment: Modem detects the router, router does not detect the modem.

Comment: So the router's Ethernet link light is off and the modem's is on? Or the link lights are on at both ends but something else indicates an error? If so, what?

Comment: The eth lights are on in both devices.

Comment: So why do you say the router isn't detecting the modem? Isn't that precisely what that light indicates? It's really important to describe *precisely* what you see and not state just conclusions. "*The router didn't detect the modem*" is a conclusion and not helpful. "*The Ethernet link light on the router for the port the modem was connected to was not lit*" is an observation and very helpful.

Comment: Using the interface, the router is unable to detect the modem to connect to the internet. Automatic DHCP for ISP fails when it should not.

Comment: Okay, so with both firmwares, you configured the router to use DHCP to get its WAN IP and with the factory firmware it didn't while with DD-WRT it did? And there were no hardware changes?

Comment: It only failed after I tried DD WRT. It used to work. Yes, no hardware changes.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue but the other way around.  When I went to dd-wrt from Merlin's firmware.  What I did was, I unplugged the Asus router for 10 seconds and also pressed the reset button while off and then again when on (doubt doing both mattered but this is what I did).  I then did the samething to my ISP's router/modem (which is bridged).  Only then was I able to get the DHCP to work with dd-wrt.

I have the new Shaw "Wide Open" 150mbit plan which I had to trade in my old router/modem and given a new one last week.  I don't like this new one I was given, its been a pain in the ass.